# Update Object Inside the Array of object in a mongoose document with projection or select

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update the object inside the document

Document: Cats

```
{
        "_id": "5e5cb512e90bd40017385305",
        "type": "cat"
        "history": [
          {
            "id": "randomID",
            "content": "xyz",
          },
          {
            "id": "randomID2",
            "content": "abc",
          }
        ]
}
```

Code to select and update the object inside the history array:

```
const editHistory = async (_, { input }, ctx) => {
  let query = { _id: input.catId, "history.id": input.historyId };
  let update = { $set: { "history.$": input.history } };
  let options = {
    new: true,
    fields: { history: { $elemMatch: { id: "randomID" } } }
  };

  let cat = await ctx.models.cats.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);

  return cat;
};
```

Input has following values

```
input: {
catId: "5e5cb512e90bd40017385305",
historyId: "randomID",
history: {
id: "randomID",
content: "new content"
}}
```

I tried using Projection, I used select changed it to field, found in mongoose documentation.
I still couldn't update the values. Is there anything wrong with the way i am querying or selecting the subfield.

Comment: `id` (document) or `_id` (query) ?

Comment: Its _id for Cat document and id for history array obejcts

Comment: What happens when you run `findOne` with the same query?

Comment: It just returns the Cat Document

Comment: @mickl is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: Tried to run your code and it works fine

Comment: @mickl did you tried the same code or findOne?

Comment: Same, `findOneAndUpdate`. The only thing I did is I changed `id` into `_id`. Can you check if you don't have both in your db?

Comment: did you change id to _id for object inside history?

Comment: No, only root level like you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Found the Solution for it by going through more detail of the operator($set) and option(new, fields).

**Question:**

```
const editHistory = async (_, { input }, ctx) => {
  let query = { _id: input.catId, "history.id": input.historyId };
  let update = { $set: { "history.$": input.history } };
  let options = {
    // using new option would return the new document
    new: true, 
    /* using fields option would select the based on the given key, but using new: 
       true with fields will throw error: 'cannot use a positional projection and 
   return the new document'
   */
    fields: { history: { $elemMatch: { id: "randomID" } } } 
  };

  let cat = await ctx.models.cats.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);

  return cat;
};
```

**This post below answers that question for *error: 'cannot use a positional projection and return the new document'.**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064082/5492398

**Final Solution:**

```
const editHistory = async (_, { input }, ctx) => {
  let query = { _id: input.catId, "history.id": input.historyId };
  let update = { $set: { "history.$": input.history } };
  let options = {
    new: true
  };

  let cat = await ctx.models.cats.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);

  return cat;
};
```

Removing field option, since I don't need the unmodified selection before atomic modification, solves the question.